# vlookup error when lookup value cell has been populated with formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, vlookup

I have the following formula which is producing a #N/A error:

```
=VLOOKUP(N8,Lookups!J5:L2772,3,FALSE)
```

The formula in N8 is:

```
=LEFT(M8,4)
```

And the value in N8 will be the first part of a UK postcode (e.g. N1, W1A, SW1Y, TF1, SO26)

I've tried changing the vlookup to an index and match formula but cannot get that to work either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks :)

[image: formulas]

[image: values]

[image: postcode lookup]

Comment: Show us your data examples

Comment: If everything works as expected, it means the value was not found. Check your data, for any unnecessary additional space or not comparing data with the same data type, that may produce such result.

Comment: Your formula returns 4 characters, but 3/5 of your examples don't. Does that mean they return more characters then intended in that case? Do you mean `=LEFT(M8,FIND(" ",M8)-1)` maybe?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I've altered the formula in N8 but that hasn't worked. I've attached images of the formulas and the value to the post. The lookup column is a list of all UK postcode prefixes/areas and there are no spaces. Where am I going wrong? Many thanks.

Comment: Your examples do not show the matches ng data you'd expect

Comment: Cracked it - I'd changed the formula to lookup from M8 instead of N8 while trying to figure out where I was going wrong. Now I've put it back to N8 - your alteration  '=LEFT(M8,FIND(" ",M8)-1)' has fixed it - thank you so much

Comment: It returned trailing spaces and you lookup data did not contain these.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula returns 4 characters.
`=LEFT(M8,FIND(" ",M8)-1)` will return the characters up to the first space (and excluding the space).

`TRIM(N8)` would also remove trailing spaces, if you plan to keep your formula as it was. In that case `=VLOOKUP(TRIM(N8),Lookups!J5:L2772,3,FALSE)` would also work, but this is less likely to throw an error:

(`=VLOOKUP(LEFT(M8,FIND(" ",M8)-1),'Lookups'!J5:L2772,3,0)`)